# App Store Connect API key fastlane multiple accounts question

Tags: ios, api, fastlane, api-key

We have a developer account that manages many other client accounts (for creating provisioning profiles, releases, etc.). So far we use cookie authentication via fastlane to upload the releases, but we want to move to the API key authentication (https://docs.fastlane.tools/app-store-connect-api).

The question is:

Do we have to create only one API key via Apple Developer Console for our account, or do we have to create a new API key for each individual client account?

Comment: Ok i figured it out, no need to create separate API key for each individual client.

Comment: I had the same question and the same conclusion but when I try to use Fastlane Match with my API Key it can't find bundle ids from other accounts. Only from the company account. I was thinking that the API Key is working cross account based on my user's permission. Have you hit such issue? Thanks!

Comment: @thinklinux Did you find any solution? I am also facing same issue as you.

Comment: @Bhavesh yeap... but not a good one :) For every account I have different API Key, issuer id and key id. Unfortunately this is the only way. We keep them secure and depending on the account we are pulling the correct ones.

Comment: @thinklinux Can I ask how do you secure them? I have to provide the .p8 file path and I don't want to commit them.

Comment: @RamyRizkalla well in the perfect scenario you should put them in some kind of vault and pull them from there when you need them. In our case our automation uses Jira, Bitrise and fastlane. We keep the metadata information for our apps in Jira and we put the keys there too. This is not very secure tho and we are going to change it in the future. The idea is to put them somewhere secure and to pull them in bitrise only while building the app.